# How to fetch user location after the app is terminated in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ios10

Want location updates even after the app terminates i.e pressing home button and swipe up the running app.but I am not getting it how to do it . I am getting location in foreground and background but not when app terminates

I am using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges but I don't know it is updating location after termination . I am saving coordinates to core data but updated locations are not shown .

Comment: The only solution is to use background mode with CoreLocation. If your app requires iOS 8, the system will relaunch your app, even if force quit by the user. This is documented in Apple Docs:

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7

Comment: thanks for the reply! could you provide me with some code.